# StackOverflowException in Json to Object / String[]

Tags: c#, json, object

I've been reading for a while now how to do this, but i never find the awnser i understand or works.

This is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Bson;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Schema;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace SongTunes
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Object Songs;

    public class Song
    {
        public int song_id { get { return song_id; } set { song_id = value; } }
        public string sorting_number { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string lyrics { get; set; }
        public string purchase_link { get; set; }
        public string youtube_id { get; set; }
        public string has_music_video { get; set; }
        public string allow_downloads { get; set; }
        public string raw_artist_id { get; set; }
        public string artist_id { get; set; }
        public string album_artist_id { get; set; }
        public string release_date { get; set; }
        public string artist_name { get; set; }
        public string album_artist_name { get; set; }
        public string album { get; set; }
        public string bitrate { get; set; }
        public string duration { get; set; }
        public string filesize { get; set; }
        public string path { get; set; }
        public string is_part_of_compilation { get; set; }
        public string visible { get; set; }
        public string track_number { get; set; }
        public string is_explicit { get; set; }
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        button1.Text = "Loading...";
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_Done(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = true;
        button1.Text = "reload";
    }


    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        string address = "";
        System.Net.WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
        string json = webclient.DownloadString(address);
        Songs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Song>>(json);
    }

    private void SongList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

It just crashes on the first

```
public int song_id { get { return song_id; } set { song_id = value; } }
```

with "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in SongTunes.exe"

Comment: Of course it will. It will cause a classic StackoverflowException. Rewrite it like `public Int32 song_id { get; set; }`

Comment: Each time you are referring to that property, it recursively calls itself again and again causing the stack to be overflew =)

Comment: Or if your intention is to explicitly indicate the body use a field `private Int32 _song_id; public Int32 song_id { get { return _song_id;} set { _song_id = value } }`

Comment: And one more last advice, don't use this kind of property names. It is not trueъ. The proper naming conventions for .NET for properties is a PascalCase. There should be data annotations or something for mapping this kind of stuff.

Comment: Oww! Thanks man, i knew it was something this easy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 public int song_id { get { return song_id; } set { song_id = value; } }
```

The get and refers to it self, this will result in a stack overflow when you calling it. If you want to save the value in a field try:

```
 private int _song_id;
 public int song_id { get { return _song_id; } set { _song_id = value; } }
```

or just change it into:

```
 public int song_id { get; set; }
```

like your other properties

Comment: And now we're here, how do i get the value of song_id in something like a MessageBox? MessageBox.Show(Song[100].song_id);?

Comment: ((Songs as Song[])[100]).song_id, your Songs object is from type object. Make it type Song[] or List<Song>.

Comment: I now have `List<Song> Songs;` but when i do `MessageBox.Show(((Songs as List<Song>)[100]).song_id);` i get **Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.**